# Relative strength and propositional indistinguishability of non-distributive lattices

Tags: lo.logic, lattice-theory

Consider the class of bounded non-distributive lattices $\mathbf{Mn}$ ($n\geqslant 3$).
[image: lattices]
(from left to right: **M3**, **M4**, **Mn**)

Now consider a propositional language over $\{\wedge,\vee,\neg\}$ with the following semantics: $\wedge$ and $\vee$ correspond to the meet and join of a lattice while $\neg$ works as follows: $\neg\top=\bot$, $\neg\bot=\top$, $\neg\mathbf{k}=\mathbf{k}$ ($\mathbf{k}\leqslant\mathbf{n}$).

For formulas $\phi$ and $\chi$ in our language say that $\phi\vDash_{\mathbf{Mn}}\chi$ iff $$\forall v:v(\phi)\leqslant_{\mathbf{Mn}}v(\phi)$$

Now we call two lattices $\mathfrak{L}$ and $\mathfrak{L}'$ *propositionally indistinguishable* iff for any two formulas over $\{\wedge,\vee,\neg\}$ $\phi$ and $\chi$ $$\phi\vDash_{\mathfrak{L}}\chi\Leftrightarrow\phi\vDash_{\mathfrak{L}'}\chi$$

We say that $\mathfrak{L}$ is *stronger* that $\mathfrak{L}'$ iff for any $\phi$ and $\chi$ $$\phi\nvDash_{\mathfrak{L}'}\chi\Rightarrow\phi\nvDash_{\mathfrak{L}}\chi$$

The question is, thus, as follows.

**Is it true that all $\mathbf{Mn}$ lattices are indistinguishable? If yes, how can we prove it (or where it has been proved)?**

---

Note: this question also appears on math stackexchange here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216838/relative-strength-and-propositional-indistinguishability-of-non-distributive-lat

Comment: It's generally a good idea to wait more than one day before crossposting.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Aren't all those lattices simple? In that case, no lattice in the family is a homomorphic image of another.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Sorry, you are right, that was a brain fart.

Comment: I assume you know that $M_1$ is distinguishable from the rest ?

Comment: Wait, isn't $M_2$ distributive and therefore distinguishable from the rest as well ? perhaps you meant $n\geq 3$ ?

Comment: Yes, totally… My bad.

Comment: The question has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216838/relative-strength-and-propositional-indistinguishability-of-non-distributive-lat